# How to set a borderColor to react native elements Avatar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, avatar

Starting to go crazy, can´t find a way of making a border and borderColor on my Avatar from react native elements. 
What im i doing wrong ? This must have an easy solution ?

[image]

```
<Avatar
      medium
      rounded
      source={{ uri: this.props.profile[0].profile_picture }}
      onPress={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}
      iconStyle={{ borderColor: 'white', borderTopLeftRadius: 1,borderStyle:'solid' }}
      containerStyle={{ borderColor:'white', borderTopLeftRadius: 1, borderStyle:'solid'  }}
      avatarStyle={{borderColor: 'white', borderTopLeftRadius: 1,borderStyle:'solid' }}
/>
```

Comment: `avatarStyle={{ border: '1px solid #fff', borderTopLeftRadius: 1 }}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add a `borderWidth`. E.g.

```
avatarStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'white', borderTopLeftRadius: 1, borderStyle:'solid' }}
```

Comment: When I used this one, it has the square picture so ugly, just removed the borderTopLeftRadius...

avatarStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderStyle: 'solid'
    }